Generar backup filtrando por rangos
Necesito respaldar la data generada por semana de una tabla especifica y posteriormente restaurarla.
La restauración no incluye algún proceso de depuración, si no que se pretende sea un histórico.
La idea es respaldar de Domingo a Sábado, por el momento tengo este script pero aun tengo dudas sobre las variables declaradas para el rango de fechas:
#!/bin/bash
# VARIABLES
FECHA=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
SERVIDOR="$(hostname)"
PASSWORD='password'
BD=ordenes
TABLA="backlogPedidos"
ARCHIVO="$SERVIDOR-${BD^^}${TABLA^^}-$FECHA.sql"
RUTA_NAS="/tmp/"


# Establecer variables para calcular el rango semanal
INICIO_SEMANA=$(date -d "last sunday - 6 days" +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
FIN_SEMANA=$(date -d "last saturday" +"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59")

# Se generar el backup por rangoo de una semana
mysqldump --databases $BD --tables $TABLA --where="fechaRegistro BETWEEN '$INICIO_SEMANA' AND '$FIN_SEMANA'" --skip-comments --compact --single-transaction --default-character-set=UTF8 --insert-ignore --complete-insert --skip-triggers --skip-routines --no-create-info --disable-keys --set-gtid-purged=OFF -q --lock-tables=false --user=backup_db -p$PASSWORD > /tmp/$ARCHIVO

echo "Backup semanal generado: $ARCHIVO"

Podrían asesorame sobre si hay otra manera más precisa de trabajarlo,por favor?

puedes hacerlo asi:
nota:
el script debe ejecutarse a las 12:01 del domingo para que funcione correctamente y abarque toda la semana
INICIO=$(date -d "last sunday 00:00:00" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
FIN=$(date -d "last saturday days 23:59:59" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

explicacion:

last saturday obtenemos el ultimo sabado y dado que es domingo, el ultimo sabado seria hace unos minutos atras.

last sunday obtenemos el ultimo domingo y dado que es domingo,  nos retornara el domingo pasado.


